# What is the simplest way to plot a decomposition tree in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to plot a "decomposition tree" in Mathematica.

I have a function `f` that takes an object and returns all the components of that object as a list.  For the purpose of this question, let's just decompose Mathematica expressions as follows (my actual `f` relies on an external database to decompose different kinds of objects, so I can't easily post it):

```
f[e_?AtomQ] := {}
f[e_] := List @@ e
```

I would like to create a tree plot that shows how an object is decomposed as we recursively keep applying `f`.  For the particular example `f` above, we should get something very similar to the output of `TreeForm`, except that a full expression should be displayed (rather than just a head) at each node.  The children of a node are going to be its components as returned by `f`.

Note that elements can repeat in a decomposition tree like this, but not elements are repeated in the output of `TreePlot` as it works with graphs.  One idea would be to generate a unique "internal name" for each node, construct a graph, and use TreePlot, setting it to display the actual form of the nodes rather than their "internal name"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
tf[x_] := f[x] /. {{} :> x, r_ :> x @@ tf /@ r}
```

[image: example usage]

If any of the terms are not inert, this "simple" (?) approach will not work.

Comment: Hackish in a way, but it's the kind of simple solution I was hoping for.  And the objects I decompose are stored as strings, so very suitable there (no accidental evaluation).

Comment: can you suggest a way compatible with this solution to change the font of the nodes?  (Needed to display glyphs not present in the default font.)

Comment: @Szabolcs You can use the `VertexRenderingFunction` option of `TreeForm` to take complete control over the node appearance, e.g. `VertexRenderingFunction->(Inset[Framed[Style[#2, FontFamily->"Webdings"], Background->LightYellow], #1]&)`.

Comment: ah, so obvious!  I was all along on the wrong track, trying to manipulate the nodes directly ...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure it answers your question, but here is how I would implement rudimentary TreeForm:

```
decompose[expr_?AtomQ] := expr
decompose[expr_] := Block[{lev = Level[expr, {1}]},
  Sow[Thread[expr -> lev]]; decompose /@ lev;]

treeForm[expr_] := Reap[decompose[expr]][[-1, 1]] // Flatten
```

Then:

[image]

**EDIT**
Yes you are right, this is not a tree. To make it a tree, each expression should carry with it its position. Kind of like so:

```
ClearAll[treePlot, node, decompose2];
SetAttributes[{treePlot, node, decompose2}, HoldAll];
decompose2[expr_] /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[expr]] := node[expr];
decompose2[expr_] := Module[{pos, list},
  pos = SortBy[
    Position[Unevaluated[expr], _, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> False], 
    Length];
  list = Extract[Unevaluated[expr], pos, node];
  list = MapThread[Append, {list, pos}];
  ReplaceList[
   list, {___, node[e1_, p1_], ___, node[e2_, p2_], ___} /; 
     Length[p2] == Length[p1] + 1 && 
      Most[p2] == p1 :> (node[e1, p1] -> node[e2, p2])]
  ]
```

Then

```
treePlot2[expr_] := 
 Module[{data = decompose2[a^2 + Subscript[b, 2] + 3 c], gr, vlbls},
  gr = Graph[data];
  vlbls = Table[vl -> (HoldForm @@ {vl[[1]]}), {vl, VertexList[gr]}];
  Graph[data, VertexLabels -> vlbls, ImagePadding -> 50]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: your plot is not really a tree, as _both_ `a^2` and `b_2` have an edge pointing to the same node labelled 2.  This is exactly the challenge (and why I mentioned that perhaps it's necessary to use an "internal name" for node): I need branching at every step, and elements are allowed to be repeated in the tree.  We should have two nodes labelled `2` here, one branching from `a^2`, the other from `b_2`.

Comment: This is brilliant coding but there is a small error. The treeplot2 function should read: Module[{data = decompose2[expr], gr, vlbls},
  gr = Graph[data];
  vlbls = Table[vl -> (HoldForm @@ {vl[[1]]}), {vl, VertexList[gr]}];
  Graph[data, VertexLabels -> vlbls, ImagePadding -> 50]
  ],